# Update title of TabPageIndicator in code

Tags: android, viewpagerindicator

I'm using [TabPageIndicator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator). I can set my own style in library of this project, but I can't dynamically edit title of tabs. What should I do to update this.